# How can I debug why Munin won't talk to Nagios?

Tags: nagios, munin

I've followed the [instructions](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToContactNagios) to connect Munin to Nagios.  NSCA is installed, `echo -e "foo.example.com\ttest\t0\t0" | /usr/sbin/send_nsca -H localhost -c /etc/send_nsca.cfg` works when run as the `munin` user, and I've added `contacts nagios` and the `contact.nagios.command /usr/bin/send_nsca -H your.nagios-host.here -c /etc/send_nsca.cfg` command to the Munin configuration.

But I don't get any NSCA messages in the logs.  Not for failing to send messages on the Munin side, or receiving messages on the Nagios side.  Here's my questions:

1. **How can I trigger alerts for Munin to be able to test?**
2. **How can I determine what step is failing?**
3. **What should I be seeing in the logs if Munin fails to send NSCA messages?**
4. **What should I be seeing in the Nagios logs if Munin succeeds in sending messages?**

Comment: Is this, by any chance, using munin 2.0.9 from the EPEL repositories on CentOS 6, and `munin-limits` isn't sending gratuitous OKs when invoked with `--force`?

Comment: How can I tell what version of munin I have installed?

Comment: Are you running Linux, and if so, what distribution?

Comment: This is Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Comment: My Debian-fu is weak, but if memory serves, `dpkg -l|grep munin`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from the instructions, but NSCA is only necessary if Nagios is **not** running on the same machine as Munin, and I see your NSCA is sending to localhost.  This makes things much easier to setup and debug.

> 1) **How can I trigger alerts for Munin to be able to test?**

No idea, but will investigate and update the answer if I discover a quick method.

> 2) **How can I determine what step is failing?**

First, make sure you have the following lines in `nagios.cfg`:

```
accept_passive_service_checks=1
check_external_commands=1
command_file=/var/lib/nagios3/rw/nagios.cmd
```

To further debug Nagios issues, enable the debug log in `nagios.cfg`:

```
debug_level=256
debug_verbosity=2
```

Restart the Nagios service and keep an eye on the following logs:

```
/var/log/nagios3/nagios.*
/var/log/munin/munin-*
```

You can manually send passive notification to a specific host and service via:

```
sudo -u nagios echo "[$(date +%s)] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;$host;$service;$result;$notes" >> $command_file
```

More info [here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/volatileservices.html).